# percentage problem in solution

Tags: linear-algebra, gre-exam

[image]
I have solve this percentage problem by back solving method. Can't I solve this straight forwardly and easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let ratio of $20\%:50\%$ be $1:x$ then, 
$$ \frac{20\% + x 50\%}{1 + x}  = 40 \% $$
[that gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.2%20%2b%20x%200.5%20=%20%281%20%2b%20x%290.4) $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

For a hand-waving solution:   The $40\%$ solution she wants is $\frac{2}{3}$ of the way from the "weak" $20\%$ stock solution to the "strong" $50\%$ stock solution, so she needs $\frac{2}{3}$ strong and $\frac{1}{3}$ weak...